# AngularJS - ng-click in an ng-repeat not executing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the following code, ng-click does not assign 'color' to 'selected_color'... why is that?

```
<div ng-app>
 <div ng-controller="xCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="color in colors" ng-click="selected_color=color" style="cursor:pointer;">{{ $index }} - {{ color }}</div>
  <hr>
  Selected Color: {{ selected_color }}
 </div>
</div>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/s6vrz184/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does, just not how you think. `ngRepeat` creates its own child scope, so in essence, each time you click, you're creating a new variable called `selected_color` on that child scope and setting it.

Create a method on your controller and call that instead:

```
$scope.setColor = function(color) {
    $scope.selected_color = color;
}
```

And use this:

```
<div ng-repeat="color in colors" ng-click="setColor(color)" style="cursor:pointer;">{{ $index }} - {{ color }}</div>
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s6vrz184/1/

If you're opposed to using a controller function for some reason, you can `$parent` to set the `selected_color` variable inline, altho this isn't recommended:

```
<div ng-repeat="color in colors" ng-click="$parent.selected_color=color" style="cursor:pointer;">{{ $index }} - {{ color }}</div>
```

`$parent` fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s6vrz184/2/